# Auto update highlighted text during scroll down (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and I badly need help about my project, Let's say this is like a yahoo inbox by which my concern is, when you highlight a message and when you use the arrow key down to navigate until the bottom. When the highlighted message hits the bottom it automatically updates the next message and highlight it, while you are still scrolling down.

[First Screenshot Sample](http://i62.tinypic.com/2nbbxw9.png)

as you can see the highlighted email is on the bottom the blue highlighted one. The next image what i want to do is when i scroll down after the last message. The highlighted text goes up and you continue scrolling down. See the next image.

[Second Picture Sample](http://i61.tinypic.com/avo7xz.png)

If there's a jsfiddle sample or a snippet it would be much more appreciated. Thank you